# How to check if object sub-children is defined?

Tags: javascript, node.js

My variable `a` in some scenarios have branch `b` and in some other - has not. How can I check if `a.b.c` is defined?

```
// scenario 1
var a = {
  b: {
    c: "d"
  }
}

// scenario 2
var a = {}
```

I tried using `typeof` but without success:

```
if (typeof a.b.c != 'undefined') {
  console.log('y', a.b.c)
} else {
  console.log('x', a.b.c)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `if (a.b.c != undefined)`.

Comment: I'm getting Error `"Cannot read property 'c' of undefined",`

Comment: Ah, right. ```if (a.b != undefined && a.b.c != undefined)``` should work then. That checks both if a.b is defined and if a.b.c is defined. Up to you whether you need both or only the first part .

Comment: I got it to work with `((a || {}).b || {}).c;` which is pretty cool (from question from duplicate).